# 2D array stored in another array Java

Tags: arrays, exception, null, 2d

Hi I am trying to store a 2D array within another 2D array so I can check which variables are not present.(It's to complicated for me to explain)

However when doing this I get a "Null pointer exception"

```
try {
    File file = new File(FILENAME);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    // Read the number of Rows and Columns first
    numberOfRows = inputFile.nextInt();
    numberOfCols = inputFile.nextInt();
    data = new int[numberOfRows][numberOfCols];

    // Complete the reading of data from the file - see Lecture Notes
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfCols; col++)  
        {
            data[row][col] = inputFile.nextInt();

            check[row][col] = data[row][col];

        }
    } 

inputFile.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error reading data from " + FILENAME + " Exception = " + ex.getMessage());
  }
```

Thank you for you help

Comment: Which line shows NPE?

Comment: check[row][col] = data[row][col];

Comment: So I think inputFIle.nextInt() is returning NPE

Comment: I added the rest of it, incase perhaps I was missing something to show you

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException occurs when we use any variable without allocation memory to it by **new** keyword
so please check your code once again possibly thease 2 variables value **numberOfRows,numberOfCols**

Comment: those two variables are fine, without the second array there is no problem with those 2 variables